# Java in NetBeans has some defects

Tags: java, netbeans

A new java project or clone file from Github running in my new environment of Netbeans has shown this exception. Please assist me to get rid of this problem. 
PO: Netbeans ide 8.0.2 and jdk1.8.0_191 is used.

```
A java.lang.IllegalArgumentException exception has occurred. 
Please report this at http://www.netbeans.org/community/issues.html, 
including a copy of your messages.log file as an attachment. The 
messages.log file is located in your 
C:\Users\kawshiqe\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\var\log folder.
```

---

[here is the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEyHy.png)

Comment: Did you look at the log?

Comment: [1] As it stands your question is far too vague. Describe exactly what you did that led to the error. Provide enough detail so that others can attempt to reproduce your problem. [2] There should be a stack trace for the error in the NetBeans log, which you can view using **View > IDE Log**. [3] Please update your question with the stack trace, and any related messages in the log. [4] As a separate matter, you are using old versions of NetBeans and JDK 8. Consider updating both to the latest versions if possible.

Comment: Netbeans has launched 11.1(not LTS) and 11.0. I didn't try further for the specific version of my post rather I started eclipse. thanks all for come forward.